# Items inserted into a TListView in Tile view always appear at the bottom of the list

Tags: listview, winapi, c++builder

I have a VCL forms application, written in C++Builder XE6, that contains a `TListView` in Tile view.

Since the `TListView` VCL component doesn't have a Tile view option, I use a `TListView` with `ViewStyle=vsReport` in the form designer and switch it to Tile view in code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormShow (TObject *Sender)
{
    TLVTileViewInfo tvi = {};

    tvi.cbSize = sizeof(tvi);
    tvi.dwMask = LVTVIM_COLUMNS;
    tvi.cLines = ListView1->Columns->Count - 1;

    ListView_SetTileViewInfo(ListView1->Handle, &tvi);

    ListView_SetView(ListView1->Handle, LV_VIEW_TILE);
}
```

The `TListView` also has `Checkboxes=true`, `GroupView=false`, `RowSelect=true`, `ShowWorkAreas=false` and `SortType=stNone`.

The `TListView` has the following `OnInsert` event handler:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ListView1Insert (TObject *Sender, TListItem *Item)
{
    TLVTileInfo ti = {};

    Item->Caption = " ";    // ComCtl32.dll throws an access violation exception when caption is empty.

    ti.cbSize    = sizeof(ti);
    ti.iItem     = Item->Index;
    ti.cColumns  = ListView1->Columns->Count - 1;
    ti.puColumns = new unsigned[ti.cColumns];
    ti.piColFmt  = new int[ti.cColumns];

    try
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < ti.cColumns; i++)
        {
            ti.puColumns[i] = 1 + i;
            ti.piColFmt [i] = LVCFMT_LEFT;
        }

        ListView_SetTileInfo(ListView1->Handle, &ti);
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete[] ti.puColumns;
        delete[] ti.piColFmt;
    }
}
```

I insert an item into the `TListView`, for example at the top:

```
TListItem* Item = ListView1->Items->Insert(0);
```

The item is inserted at the top of the list (`Item->Index` is 0 after the insertion), but appears at the bottom of the list view on screen.

When I delete an item, the list view shows an empty space where the tile used to be.
I fixed this with the following code after the deletion:

```
ListView_Arrange(ListView1->Handle, LVA_DEFAULT);
```

This removes the empty space from the list view.

Unfortunately, this has no effect when called after the insertion of an item. Newly inserted items remain displayed at the bottom of the list view.

If I insert an item into the list view in Report view, all works as expected. Just not when in Tile view.

How do I get the list view to display the items in the correct order (i.e. ascending order of the `Index` property of the items) in Tile View?

**Update**

As it turns out, switching the view to any other type and back to `LV_VIEW_TILE` causes the list view to arrange the items in the proper order.

This can be done after inserting the new item:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click (TObject *Sender)
{
    ListView1->Items->BeginUpdate();    // Disable repainting list view.

    try
    {
        TListItem* Item = ListView1->Items->Insert(0);

        Item->Caption = "New item";

        ListView_SetView(ListView1->Handle, LV_VIEW_LIST);  // Can be any LV_VIEW_... value other than LV_VIEW_TILE.
        ListView_SetView(ListView1->Handle, LV_VIEW_TILE);
    }
    __finally
    {
        ListView1->Items->EndUpdate();  // Enable repainting list view.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code as a work around, does what you want and you won't even notice the switch from list to tile views.

```
    void __fastcall TForm3::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
    {
    ViewList();                             //  set ViewStyle to  LV_VIEW_LIST
    TListItem *item;
    item = ListView1->Items->Insert(2);     //  insert it @ item index 2
                                            //  or ListView1->Items->Insert(ListView1->Selected->Index);
    item->Caption = "Hello 1";
    ViewTile();                             //  restore view to LV_VIEW_TILE 
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm3::ViewTile()
    {
    //set view to Tile View
    TLVTileViewInfo tvi = {};

    tvi.cbSize = sizeof(tvi);
    tvi.dwMask = LVTVIM_COLUMNS;
    tvi.cLines = ListView1->Columns->Count - 1;

    ListView_SetTileViewInfo(ListView1->Handle, &tvi);

    ListView_SetView(ListView1->Handle, LV_VIEW_TILE);

    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm3::ViewList()
    {
    // restore view to List View aka vsReport
    TLVTileViewInfo tvi = {};

    tvi.cbSize = sizeof(tvi);
    tvi.dwMask = LVTVIM_COLUMNS;
    tvi.cLines = ListView1->Columns->Count - 1;

    ListView_SetTileViewInfo(ListView1->Handle, &tvi);

    ListView_SetView(ListView1->Handle, LV_VIEW_LIST);
    }
```

Add your ListView_Arrange(ListView1->Handle, LVA_DEFAULT); to your Delete1Click event of your popup menu (you already do that but shown here for others).

```
    void __fastcall TForm3::Delete1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
ListView1->DeleteSelected();
ListView_Arrange(ListView1->Handle, LVA_DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As it turns out, switching the view to any other type and back to `LV_VIEW_TILE` is what does the trick. BTW, no need to call `ListView_SetTileViewInfo()`, because the tile info remains set when switching views.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the blog post [Positioned vs. non-positioned listview views](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040712-00/?p=38483) by Raymond Chen, I found another way to insert a new item, which doesn't require toggling the view:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click (TObject *Sender)
{
    TPoint P;
    
    // Get position of item to insert before (in this case: the 1st item in the list).
    ListView_GetItemPosition(ListView1->Handle, 0, &P);
    
    // Insert new item (will be positioned at the bottom of the list).
    TListItem* Item = ListView1->Items->Insert(0);
    
    Item->Caption = "New item";

    // Move new item to same position as item inserted before (now the 2nd item in the list).    
    ListView_SetItemPosition(ListView1->Handle, Item->Index, P.X, P.Y);
    
    // Rearrange items in the list.
    ListView_Arrange(ListView1->Handle, LVA_DEFAULT);
}
```